# Find An Entire Function $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=a_n$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Is there an entire function $f(z)$ such that $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=a_n$ where:
>
> $a_n=\left\{0,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{4},0,\frac{1}{6},0,\dots\right\}$

I understood that the identity theorem should be in used, but I can not understand how

Comment: No, it is not. An [entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) is an analytic function from $\mathbb C$ into itself. That's a standard expression.

Comment: $$z·\cos^2\big(\frac{\pi}{2z}\big)$$ has the correct values but also an essential singularity at $z=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Well $f$ has zeroes at $1,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{5},\dots$. Therefore, $f$ vanishes on a sequence of distinct points with a limit point in $\mathbb{C}$. Therefore, $f$ must be identically $0$ (since $f$ is entire). So such an $f$ does not exist.

Comment: Why f is identically 0?

Comment: @gbox By the identity theorem.

Comment: It depends what you call "the identity theorem". There's a theorem saying "if $f$ is holomorphic in a region $\Omega$ and $f$ vanishes on a sequence of distinct points of $\Omega$ with a limit point in $\Omega$, then $f \equiv 0$ on $\Omega$.